# What changes Agent K to be happier?

Tags: men-in-black-3

In the last scene at the diner in Men in Black 3 Agent K is humming a tune that is playing.
Agent J is confused how he knows the song. What changed? What makes Agent K happier now than he used to be?

Comment: just the opposite, I don't even think that question is correct. Isn't K clearly less grumpy and not more grumpy?

Comment: To quote from that question: *"As far as I know, though, the only thing that changed was that he killed Boris the Animal rather than arresting him, so what changed him so much for the better?"*

Comment: ok i was refering to another question. This one is similar.